# How to save nested POJO object with id (@DocumentId)?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have two models:

```
UserModel:  
 @DocumentId id  
 ...
```

and

```
MessageModel:
  @DocumentId id
  user: UserModel
```

When I save **MessageModel** there is a **user object inside message document**, **but without user id**, how can I save user id too?

**I have** document:

```
{msgId}
  text: "Blah",
  user: {
    name: "UserName"
  }
```

**I want** to have document:

```
{msgId}
  text: "Blah",
  user: {
    id: "{userId}",
    name: "UserName"
  }
```

Comment: Probably reconsider the data-structure; neither makes much sense to me; eg. `userId: "{userId}"`. So what if a user changes his `name`?

Comment: @MartinZeitler any suggestions? I want to save messages with user who sent the messages

Comment: Most easy might be `userId`, `message`, `timestamp`. Else when adding features later, you might realizes that they might be "limited by design"; keeping it simple is often an advance. Not that one couldn't update all the `username` fields, but this effort can be prevented by not storing them with each message.

Comment: @MartinZeitler, I want to show list of the messages and users name|image who sents the messages.
You'll suggest me to make 1 query to get list of the messages and make n queries to get the message user?

can you please explain

Comment: If each chat has a list of `userId ` participating, one can easily look them up on demand... and in the client, these might even be already known, by the list of contacts one has.

Comment: @MartinZeitler, I have chat and messages inside the chat, each message has user model.
In case then I save only userId to message, I have to load N messages and after make another request to get users for the N messages and merge them.